# Integrate $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\log(1-x^2)}{(1-\beta x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, logarithms

I would like to integrate the following:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} dx \frac{\log(1-x^2)}{(1-\beta x)^2}$$

where $\beta$ is real and greater than zero.
While it looks like this diverges I have a reference which has a closed finite form.

How do I integrate this?

Comment: sorry mistake in the boundaries, this should have been $1$ and $-1$

Comment: maybe we need $0 \le \beta < 1$ for the convergence

Comment: This is indeed the case, $0 \leq \lvert \beta \rvert <1$ but Mathematica seems to be giving me a diverging result.

Comment: Maple says
$$
2\,{\frac {2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) \beta+\ln  \left( -\beta+1
 \right) -\ln  \left( \beta+1 \right) }{\beta\, \left(1- {\beta}^{2}
 \right) }}
$$

Comment: I need to get Maple... thanks!

Comment: You may first compute the antideriative using integration by parts and then follow Claude Leibovici's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the problem with Mathematica came from the fact that you computed first the antiderivative
$$I(x)=\int \frac{\log \left(1-x^2\right)}{(1-\beta  x)^2}\,dx$$ which gives
$$ I(x)=\frac1\beta\left(\frac{\log \left(1-x^2\right)}{1-\beta  x}-\frac{2 \log (1-\beta  x)}{\beta
   ^2-1}+\frac{\log (1-x)}{\beta -1}-\frac{\log (x+1)}{\beta +1}\right)$$ and that you tried to compute $I(1)$ and $I(-1)$ which are undefined.

Asking directly for the definite integral would have given the result.

Starting from the antiderivative, you could have computed $I(1-\epsilon)-I(-1+\epsilon)$ and developing the result as a Taylor series built around $\epsilon=0$ would give
$$\frac{4}{\beta(1 -\beta ^2) }\left(\beta  \log (2)- \tanh ^{-1}(\beta )\right)-\frac{2 \left(\beta ^2+1\right)}{\left(\beta ^2-1\right)^2}\epsilon  \log \left(\frac{2 \epsilon }{e}\right)+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ and then the limit
$$\int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{\log \left(1-x^2\right)}{(1-\beta  x)^2}\,dx=\frac{4}{\beta(1 -\beta ^2) }\left(\beta  \log (2)- \tanh ^{-1}(\beta )\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\to -x$ over $(-1,0)$

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{(1-\beta x)^2}dx
= & \ 2\int_0^1\ln(1-x^2) \frac{1+\beta^2x^2}{(1-\beta^2x^2)^2} dx\\
 = & \ 2\int_0^1 \ln(1-x^2)\ d\left( \frac{x}{1-\beta^2x^2} - \frac{1}{1-\beta^2}\right)\\
 \overset{ibp}= & \ \frac4{1-\beta^2}\int_0^1\frac1{1+x}-\frac1{1-\beta^2x^2}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac4{1-\beta^2}\left(\ln2-\frac1{2\beta}\ln \frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}\right)
\end{align}